# String Format double to 00,00 - Java

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm trying to make a double to be this format 00,00

> Example
>
> 9,21341 > 09,21
>
> 10,4312 > 10,43
>
> 1,01233 > 01,01
>
> 42,543 > 42,54

Currently I'm using the String.Format to round the double

```
String.format("%s %02.2f - ", example.getName(), example.getDouble());
```

This does not add the extra zero in front of the double if it is smaller than 10.

Comment: The field width is 2 - that's not enough for a number, a dot, and two digits after that dot. So the field size is exceeded already - how do you expect it to pad to the left?

Comment: Did you try to cast?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class (which is the basis of `String.format` method) operates using the concept of "fields". That is, each field is of some specific size and can be padded. In your case, you could use a formating like `%05.2f`, which would mean a field of size 5, with 2 symbols after the point padded with zeroes to the left.

However, if you need some fine-grained formatting of numbers usually what you are looking for is [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class, which allows you to easily customize how the numbers are represented.

Example ([ideone link](https://ideone.com/VwJyEB)):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#00.00");
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(0.99f));
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(9.99f));
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(19.99f));
        System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(119.99f));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
00.99
09.99
19.99
119.99
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I converted it to the DecimalFormat. It works like a charm :)